# Why won't my text editor recognize an installed Python module?

Tags: python

I installed the pyinputplus module to my Mac using terminal, but when trying to use the module in Mu Editor, I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus.'" How do I get this text editor to recognize this module?

Comment: The usual explanation for problems like this is that your editor/IDE is configured to use a different installed Python version than your terminal.

Comment: i agree with @jasonharper. and also, it could be a package installation path issue. maybe you installed your module in one directory and your editor is looking for it in another one. if you installed the package using pip, you can check the directory with pip show "package-name"